# Is there an interface similar to Callable but with arguments?

Tags: java, interface

Is there an interface in Java similar to the `Callable` interface, that can accept an argument to its call method?

Like so:

```
public interface MyCallable<V> {
  V call(String s) throws Exception;
}
```

I would rather avoid creating a new type if there already exists something that I can use. Or is there a better strategy to having multiple clients implement and plug in a callable routine?

Copied from here http://www.programmingforums.org/thread27905.html

Comment: Nope, but see things like http://www.programmingforums.org/thread27905.html.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since Java 8 there is a whole set of Function-like interfaces in [the `java.util.function` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). The one you're asking for specifically is simply [`Function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

Prior to Java 8, there was no general-purpose, built-in interface for this, but some libraries provided it.

For example [Guava](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has [the `Function<F,T>` interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) with the method `T apply(F input)`. It also makes [heavy use of that interface](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#functions-and-predicates) in several places.

Comment: This same question occurred to my co-workers last week. Our first and obvious choice was to use Function<F,T> from Guava. However we noticed that the apply() method didn't throw exceptions. This rendered it unsuitable for our purposes. Unfortunately, we had to end up creating our own interface for that. At least it got into a company-wide lib, to be re-used.

Comment: @FilipeFedalto: well, both exception-throwing and non-throwing `Function` can be useful. Most uses of `Function` in Guava are simple "convert a-to-b" and "get foo from Bar object" uses that should never (in a sane program) throw a checked exception (NPE and the unchecked ones are a different story). That's (probably) why the Guava `Function` doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ with it?  An interface like this is only useful if implementing it lets you do things better than you could with a direct implementation.  This isn't always true with `Function`, let alone more complicated beasts.

Answer (score 9):

at first it thought that this is done with an interface but then i found that it should be done using an abstract class.

i have solved it this way:

---

edit: lately i just use this:

```
    public static abstract class callback1<T>{
         public abstract  void run(T value);
    }

    public static abstract class callback2<T,J>{
         public abstract  void run(T value,J value2);
    }

    public static abstract class callback3<T,J,Z>{
         public abstract  void run(T value,J value2,Z value3);
    }


    public static abstract class callbackret1<R,T>{
         public abstract  R run(T value);
    }

    public static abstract class callbackret2<R,T,J>{
         public abstract  R run(T value,J value2);
    }

    public static abstract class callbackret3<R,T,J,Z>{
         public abstract  R run(T value,J value2,Z value3);
    }
```

---

**CallBack.java**

```
public abstract class CallBack<TRet,TArg> {
    public abstract TRet call(TArg val);
}
```

**define method:**

```
class Sample2 
{
    CallBack<Void,String> cb;
    void callcb(CallBack<Void,String> CB)
    {
     cb=CB; //save the callback
     cb.call("yes!"); // call the callback
    }
}
```

**use method:**

```
sample2.callcb(new CallBack<Void,String>(){
        @Override
        public Void call(String val) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    });
```

two arguments sample: **CallBack2.java**

```
public abstract class CallBack2<TRet,TArg1,TArg2> {
    public abstract TRet call(TArg1 val1,TArg2 val2);
}
```

notice that when you use Void return type you have to use return null;
so here is a variation to fix that because usually callbacks do not return any value.

void as return type: **SimpleCallBack.java**

```
public abstract class SimpleCallBack<TArg> {
    public abstract void call(TArg val);
}
```

void as return type 2 args: **SimpleCallBack2.java**

```
public abstract class SimpleCallBack<TArg1,TArg2> {
    public abstract void call(TArg1 val1,TArg2 val2);
}
```

interface is not useful for this.

interfaces allow multiple types match same type. by having a shared predefined set of functions.

abstract classes allow empty functions inside them to be completed later. at extending or instantiation.

Comment: I also think your `CallBack` abstract class should be an interface, if only to allow multiple inheritance (quick example: have a child class extend one of your classes, and be a `CallBack` at the same time). What made you change your opinion?

Comment: i have a feeling thtat you can cast before passing it as argument. also the abstract class can implement an interface you can put as argument and not require casting

Comment: I still do not see the advantage of using an abstract class: those are most useful when used to provide methods that must be implemented in subclasses along with a skelettal implementation that eases the development of the subclasses. Here you do not have any code in your abstract classes, just abstract methods. Hence, you could just use interfaces instead.

Comment: abstract classes are like puzzles with a missing piece you can complete with your own code. interfaces,  in strongly typed languages, are a utility to match any multiple types. however, you must first declare a class. therefore you need some abstract class to put a method inside of it.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same requirement recently. As others have explained many libs do provide 'functional' methods, but these do not throw exceptions.

An example of how some projects have provided a solution is the *RxJava* library where they use interfaces such as *ActionX* where 'X' is 0 ... N, the number of arguments to the *call* method. They even have a varargs interface, *ActionN*.

My current approach is to use a simple generic interface:

```
public interface Invoke<T,V>  {     
    public T call(V data) throws Exception;     
//  public T call(V... data) throws Exception;    
}
```

The second method is preferable in my case but it exhibits that dreaded "Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter data" in my IDE, and that is a whole other issue.

Another approach I am looking at is to use existing interfaces such as *java.util.concurrent.Callable* that do not throw Exception, and in my implementation wrap exceptions in unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 1.8 there is a `Supplier<T>` interface. It has a `get()` method instead of `call()` and it does not declare any Exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ambiguous. Strictly speaking, that is, "for the same purpose of the Callable interface", there is not.

There are similar classes, and depending on what you want, they may or may not be convenient. One of them is the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). However, as the name implies, it was designed for use within the Swing framework. It could be used for other purposes, but this would be a poor design choice.

My best advice is to use one provided by an extension library (Jakarta-Commons, Guava, and so on), depending on what libraries you already use in your system.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. you can wrap any method to return a callable, and execute it's returned value.
i.e.

```
 main {    
    Callable<Integer> integerCallable = getIntegerCallable(400);
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(integerCallable);
}

private Callable<Integer> getIntegerCallable(int n) {
    return () -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(n);
                return 123;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("task interrupted", e);
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally arguments are not required as the method can have any number of arguments in its constructor.

```
final int i = 5;
final String word = "hello";

Future<String> future = service.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() {
        return word + i;
    }
});
```

In this example `i` and `word` have been used, but you can "pass" any number of parameters.

Comment: Actually you is correct, BUT just to Extend, from many point of view create new Callable object each time can be overhead and useless. Example — then you process big collection by single element, one by one, Or when you have some Component and you should delivery process to him (to avoid mix/mess logics).

Comment: @iMysak To pass work between threads via a queue you are going to be creating quite a few objects (at least 3 I suspect)

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface like so:

```
interface MyFunction<I, O> {
    O call(I input);
}
```

Define a method:

```
void getOrderData(final Function<JSONArray, Void> func){
    ...
    JSONArray json = getJSONArray();
    if(func!=null) func.call(json);           
}
```

Usage example:

```
//call getOrderData somewhere in your code
getOrderData(new Function<JSONArray, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JSONArray input) {
            parseJSON(input);                
            return null;
        }
});
```