# Is there any standard 'gettable' Java interface?

Tags: java, interface

I need to expose few containers to different component and what I actually need here is just:

```
interface Gettable {
    public String get(String key);
}
```

Is there any standard Java (SE) interface as close to this as it is possible to not introduce yet another one but limit exposed container behavior to needed minimum?

UPDATE:
Selected solution is custom interface. I really'd like to keep it as generic as it is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an interface similar to Callable but with arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083868/is-there-an-interface-similar-to-callable-but-with-arguments)

Comment: Is what you need really a Gettable or either a Cache, Map, Registry, Parameters, ... ? I mean Gettable is not a self-explanatory name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with another custom interface.

```java
public interface Gettable<K, V> {
    public V get(K key);
}
```

Comment: Reads like "get table".

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest standard interface there is, is `java.util.Map`. Note that many methods of Map are optional (may thorw an UnsupportedOperationException).

Comment: `Map` has **a lot** of baggage in addition to this one method, it has pretty explicit contracts and using it to implement just that single method is an abuse of the interface in my opinion.

Comment: yes and no. The required methods mainly cover stuff like "is the argument valid?" (contains, isEmpty) and methods to iterate over "all these things you can get" (size, key/value/entry collections). But, of course, I see your point, which is why I mentioned "the closest standard interface".

Comment: Ok,probably it's option but I really dislike its `get(Object)` signature.

Answer (score -3):

Guava is almost like a Java standard, and they have `Function` ([javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html)) which has the signature you are looking for

`T apply(F input)`

> Returns the result of applying this function to input.

Comment: The signature doesn't allow for an argument, unfortunately. So it's almost exactly what he *doesn't* want :-)